# Best practices regarding value objects

Tags: domain-driven-design

I had a few questions around value objects in DDD.

I had a class `ReportDefinition` (basically a schema for a specific report that users can create) with the following properties (in Java):

```
UUID id;
UUID ownerId;
UUID organizationId;
ReportDefinitionName name;
ReportTitle reportTitle;
ReportDescription reportDescription;
Instant createdAt;
Instant lastModifiedAt;
```

As you can see, there everything is a value object. So far, all the value objects in the systems have been wrappers around a single primitive (Strings for the most part). i.e. to get the report title as a string, I would do `reportDefinition.reportTitle().title()`.

Yesterday I needed to add another property, `ReferenceType`. I came to the realization that `reportTitle`, `reportDescription` and the `referenceType` should probably be grouped together another value object, `ReportDetails`. I can see the need for `referenceType` to still be a value object, but not sure if I should change `title` and `description` to simple strings within the `ReportDetails`?

At the moment, `ReportTitle` and `ReportDescription` do some simple validations (i.e. report title must be between 1 and 60 characters, etc), but that's about it. If I made them strings, I could still do the basic validation checks within `ReportDetails`.

Another question that arises is whether this might lead to violation of the law of demeter. i.e. it's like that the application layer will need to call `reportDefinition.reportDetails.title().title()` which is starting to get a bit crazy.

And finally, given that value objects should be immutable, I'm guessing if I wanted to update the report details, I might need methods like `ReportDetails updateTitle(title)` that returns a new instance of `ReportDefinition`. I was wondering who should actually call that method? i.e. should it be a protected method within `ReportDetails` and called via a `void updateTitle()` method on the `ReportDefinition`? Or is it fine for the application layer to call `reportDetails.updateTitle()` and then pass the result to an `updateReportDetails()` method on `ReportDefinition`?

Part of the reason why it made sense to split them out into a seperate object was because a `Report` will need the information in `ReportDetails` when being created (whereas the rest of the information in `ReportDefinition` is irrelevant and deals with other concerns).

The immutability is an artefact of following DDD and not wanting consumers of the class to modify `ReportDetails` simply on account of having a reference to it. A business case is that `ReportDetails` can only be change when `ReportDefinition` is in a draft state (not shown above) whereas the other information in `ReportDefinition` can always be changed.

Comment: Your problems seem to have started when you decided to add some "enhancements" without justifying them.  `ReportDetails` is the first enhancement, immutability is the second.  Have you considered whether the benefits you derive from these enhancements outweigh the additional complexity that they bring to your project?

Comment: @RobertHarvey added more details to the question in response to your comment

Answer (score 3):

Immutable is a wonderful thing, but the main reason why is not because DDD said so, because of threads, or even because it protects against nonsense. No the main reason is because immutable value objects are easier to read. Easier to reason about.

But they come at a cost. You only get one moment in time to build them.

I really don't understand why you're going through 4 layers to get a title when `report.getTitle()` should be the end of it.

Comment: There's a distinction between a `ReportDefinition` and a `Report`. A `ReportDefinition` is a template for a specific type of `Report`, alongside some other information (i.e. the `ReportDefinitionName` is the name of the `ReportDefinition` and nothing to do with `Reports`).The `Report` itself will have a getter to get the title.

Think of `ReportDetails.ReportTitle` as being a templated string. A specific instance of a `Report` has some template variables that are used to resolve the title.

Comment: Still don't understand. `reportDefinition.getTitle()` gets the report definition's title. I can't see what `reportDefinition.reportDetails.title().title()` is getting you. What's wrong with `reportDefinition.getTitle().toString()`?

Comment: A `ReportDefinition` has a name (`reportDefintion.getName()`) but the `title` isn't a direct child of `ReportDefinition`, it's part of the schema / template for a `Report` that `ReportDefinition` has. That schema has a number of other fields as well that are all used to help build a `Report`. The `ReportDefinition` has other fields which don't relate to building `Reports` (i.e. isDraft, createdTime, ownerId, etc), which is why I've created the `ReportDetails` object.

Comment: With that said, I can do what you suggested, however I feel that `reportDefinition.getReportDetails().getTitle()` might make the API a bit clearer. i.e. having a method `getName()` and `getTitle()` on the `ReportDefinition` might be confusing to a user (what's the difference between the two?). Don't mind the `toString()`, I think that's better than having `.title()` at the end of the chain.

Comment: Let me ask it this way, why does code that uses report details need to know that report definitions exist?

Comment: The only time I think it's needed is probably for the form to edit a report definition. In most other cases, an instance of `ReportDetails` will just be passed in.

Comment: Then in those cases where it's passed in you don't have a Demeter problem. You can just use `reportDetails.title()`. But remember [Demeter is not just a dot counting exercise](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/284146/131624).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have quite a complex object there. Too complex for a specific answer. But I would make the following observations:

- It seems like a bad idea to enforce business rules via immutability.
- Having all you rules in property setters is also somewhat confusing.
- Add some methods to the top level object ie. Report.ChangeTitle(string title) and hide the complexity of report.reportDetail.reportTitle.title behind them.

An object which its impossible for the *programmer* to break rules with, due to immutability, setters, private methods or clever tricks with builders and interfaces is a wonderful thing to see and use.

But its much harder to achieve than an object which is impossible for the *user* to break rules with.