# Law of Demeter and over-wide interfaces

Tags: design, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, code-smell, law-of-demeter

The [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) makes sense in some obvious cases.

```
# better
dog.walk()

# worse
dog.legs().front().left().move()
dog.legs().back().right().move()
# etc.
```

But in other cases it seems to lead to an interface that is too wide, and doesn't really feel like it "hides" any knowledge.

```
# Is this worse?
print(account.user().fullName())
print(account.user().socialSecurityNumber())

# Is this better?
print(account.userFullname())
print(account.userSocialSecurityNumber())
```

It feels like account has methods for things that really aren't anything to do with accounts now, just to avoid a technical violation of the Law of Demeter. Instictively, `account.userFullName()` is pretty "code smelly".

Is anyone aware of any more specific guidelines or refinements of the LoD that helps account for the difference between the "dog" cases where the principle clearly makes sense, and the cases where it doesn't? And how do you avoid the LoD leading to over-wide interfaces?

One principle I have heard is that it [matters less in a context of immutability](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/law-of-demeter-and-immutability/), but many have [disputed this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12611651).

Comment: If you need a guideline, then [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter#In_object-oriented_programming) should work.

Comment: @laiv that's just structural thinking. That could be enforced by a static code analyzer. Java 8 Streams prove that there are good exceptions to these rules. It's best to understand [why the rules exist](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/284146/131624).

Comment: What about a 3-legged dog?  Or an account with 2 users?

Comment: For internal code I try to make my code follow the "worse" example. Hiding knowledge is good for consumers, but not so helpful when trying to debug or extend.

Answer (score 39):

```
# better
dog.walk()

# worse
dog.legs().front().left().move()
dog.legs().back().right().move()
# etc.
```

There are two reasons why the second is worse. The first, not really directly LOD-related, is that your walk logic isn't reusable, which is a problem in the case where there are multiple places in your codebase where a dog must walk.

The LOD-related reason why this code is bad is because it forces the current consumer to know that `DogLeg` exists and how to operate it. The unspoken expectation here is that your consumer only knows about a `Dog`, and that it can be made to move around, but *how* that `Dog` moves around isn't something the consumer cares about (that's up to the `Dog` to manage for themselves).

However, that is not necessarily the case for your other example.

```
account.user().fullName()
```

If `Account` and `User` are both domain objects of which your consumer has public knowledge, then there's no issue with asking them to handle a `User` object directly.
The expectation here is that "the account refers to its owner" is part of the `Account` interface, and therefore returning the owner (represented by a `User` object) is fair game.

Comparatively, your `Dog` interface is not expected to include "the dog has legs", but rather "the dog is able to **move around**", and the legs are just an implementation detail so the dog is able to fulfill its contract (i.e. moving around). The interface itself doesn't specify the existence of legs, and therefore the consumer of `Dog` shouldn't be relying on the existence of legs.

In essence, a `DogLeg` is considered a private implementation detail, whereas a `User` (class) is publically known. This means that there's significantly less issue with expecting your consumer to handle a `User` than there is with expecting them to handle a `DogLeg`.

That being said, if `account.user()` was actually an `AccountUser` object which would also be considered a private implementation detail, then the same principle applies as it does for `DogLeg`.

This is what makes LOD so tricky to pinpoint. It's not something that is objectively true based on your code alone, it hinges on subjective context and expectation of interfaces/contracts. By renaming the code, you change the reader's implicit expectation, which can change whether something is considered an LOD violation.

```
dog.legs().front()
account.user().fullName()
```

Technically, it's the same code. But what changes is our expectation of how acceptable it is to force a consumer to directly handler a `DogLeg` vs forcing them to handle a `User`.

Comment: The meaning of LoD in this regard is not really up for debate, it is quite clearly written. Calling methods on instance variables of other objects is not allowed. It doesn't matter what the user of the code or the writer expects.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam the law is clear, but it's a rule of thumb, not an actual law. The question isn't "what does the law say?", but "should I listen to the law in this case?". It should make you ask questions like this, not automatically refactor every line with two or more dots.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam _"Calling methods on instance variables of other objects is not allowed."_ [The Law of Demeter is not a dot counting exercise](https://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/14/law-of-demeter-dot-counting.aspx/). You cannot and _should not_ judge LOD violations based on the accessing code itself. The surrounding context matters in making the accessing code applicable or non-applicable to LOD considerations.

Comment: I've made a factual observation about your comment. Whether something is or is not a LoD violation _does not_ depend on the "reader's implicit expectation" as you've tried to argue. That's it. Am I wrong? For reference, here's the [original paper](https://www2.ccs.neu.edu/research/demeter/papers/law-of-demeter/oopsla88-law-of-demeter.pdf).

Comment: @RobertBräutigam: It seems you misunderstood my answer. The implicit expectation of the reader **of the example code** does matter, because we (as the reader) have to infer what the intended contract of the `Dog` and `Account` classes is. Example code in questions is usually light on rigorous analysis documentation that would shed light on the things that we are now left to infer. So whether or not we designate this example code as a LOD violation or not, hinges on our implicit inference on what is the contract and what is a private implementation detail.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam: Just to finish that thought, based on the presented example code, it's in my opinion reasonable to infer that a dog's legs are an implementation detail and the `Dog` contract only stipulates _movement_; whereas the `Account` contract likely stipulates that it has an owner (represented by a `User`, whose contract in turn stipulates that users have a last name) and not that the account contains its owner's last name specifically. I cannot guarantee that this is correct, but this is why it's called an inference.

Comment: @Flater by I like this idea of telling the objective and let the class carry it out without worrying for implementation details: `dog.goto(master)` seems simpler than telling the route. I didn’t elaborate on dog in my own answer because there’s no LoD issue (if a class knows about dog, we can assume it can use its public interface; we can argue about granularity of interface but this is not LoD relevant in this case imho)

Comment: @Flater the law of demeter is not subjective, you simply choose whether or not it is worth fixing.

Comment: This is a great answer and illustrates why dogmatic adherence to the LoD is generally misguided.

Comment: @user949300 Hehe, "dogmatic" :) I see what you did there :)

Comment: `account.getUser().getName()`  will cause the troubles LoD tries to prevent you from if `user` changes and that's not a matter of perspective. It will turn into red all the classes coupled to `user`, whether you belive `user` must be accessible for everybody any place or not. If you need access to the `user` then pass the `user` not the account. How and who retrieves `user` from `account`  is a different matter.

Comment: @Laiv: If the `Account` contract stipulated that it contains a reference to a `User`, then this is not an LOD violation. This means that the consumer who calls `account.getUser()` is inherently expected to be able to work with a `User` object, since the `Account` class contract isn't set up to do it for them. There is a difference between "an account contains its owner's name (and storing that name in a `User` is an implementation detail" and "an account contains a reference to its owner (i.e. `User`)". In the former, `account.getUser().fullname()` is an LOD violation, in the latter it is not.

Comment: @Flater then the consumer is inherently expected to know about the interface of `User` and so on. LoD sets the limits where this `inherently` should end.

Comment: @Laiv: The "inherently" ends based on how the contracts have been stipulated. LOD at its very core aims to disallow directly handling private implementation details, and instead tells you to only use the contract as it has been specified (and, by extension, to develop your classes so that their private implementation details don't leak and you adhere to their contract).

Comment: @Laiv: People always tersely summarize LOD as "don't talk to strangers", but I'd argue that it's more a matter of "don't handle others' privates, even if they've exposed them". But that's maybe a less SFW interpretation.

Comment: By this reasoning (the contract interpretation) I could argue that `DogLeg` is expected to be part of the `Dog` public contract and hence not breaking LoD either. If yo leave it open to interpretation then LoD is useless. If you want to narrow down the coupling of certain elements you need to set a sort of rules of thumb. Rules you can break when is convenient. The account example could be one of these convenient cases. But it doesn't mean you are not breaking LoD because you are inherently inheriting the issues LoD is trying to prevent. This is not good nor bad. But it's what it's.

Comment: Anyways, I agreed, Principles and "laws" should be read and interpreted carefully and applied in the way that best meets your needs.  Even break'em occasionally if need it.

Comment: @Laiv: You can definitely argue that interpretation, but my answer explicitly mentions that calling it a LOD violation is based on the inference that a dog leg is not considered part of the `Dog` contract. It assumes a contract like `interface IDog { void Move(); }` where it only stipulates _that_ a dog can move. _How_ that dog moves is a private implementation detail. Whether it uses legs, hoverjets, or wind sails is irrelevant as far as the contract is concerned. But I agree that OP left the contract up to inference, cfr my comment to RobertBrautigam (13 comments up from here).

Answer (score 26):

The LoD or [principle of least knowledge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) has nothing to do with immutability. It’s about decoupling systems by decreasing indirect dependencies.

In your dog case, you only need to know about dogs to make your chained invocations.

In your account case, when some module is working with accounts, it also needs to know about users, and perhaps even about addresses. So it’s not just about friends but also about friends of friends. This leads to complex and time-consuming change propagation: e.g. a change in the address class may impact user class and account class.

The way out is to tell objects what they should do without micromanaging the details:

```
account.print();  // account will invoke user.print()
```

This is of course easier said than done, because this may create other issues (e.g. bloated interfaces if you need `printSumary()` and `printDetails()`). And sometimes, you just need to know about friends of closer friends. In the end the design will not be about respecting all the “laws” but about balancing different principles to get an optimal fit.

Answer (score 4):

Adding more methods to an interface is not always the solution to the Law of Demeter. You do not need to distinguish these cases, you need to find a different way to resolve them.

From the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter#Disadvantages):

> On the other hand, at the class level, if the LoD is not used correctly, wide (i.e. enlarged) interfaces may be developed that require introducing many auxiliary methods. This is due to poor design rather than a consequence of the LoD per se. If a wrapper method is being used, it means that the object being called through the wrapper should have been a dependency in the calling class.

Take your second example:

```
print(account.user().fullName())
print(account.user().socialSecurityNumber())
```

Does your caller here need to interact with an account at all? Remove account as a dependency and provide user as an argument instead:

```
print(user.fullname())
print(user.socialSecurityNumber())
```

Comment: Indeed, it’s all a question of balance between the different principles and needs. In fact, adding new methods like that may even create a hidden coupling (e.g. if for privacy reasons you’d get rid of social security in the user, you’d have to change a lot of methods.

Answer (score 0):

## Decide Who Your Neighbors Are

The premise of this law is not to avoid "chaining" of function calls (or property/field access, etc.), but rather to limit the "reach" of one class of objects. In the case of the walking dog, the caller must know about the dog, a collective structure that contains all of the legs, and about an individual leg. This requires tight coupling between the consumer and the leg details, so it's better to let the dog handle its own legs.

### Starting at the beginning

User [Robert Bräutigam](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/232369/robert-br%c3%a4utigam) linked to the [original paper](https://www2.ccs.neu.edu/research/demeter/papers/law-of-demeter/oopsla88-law-of-demeter.pdf) in a comment to another answer. I thought it best to transcribe the actual text of the "law" here:

> For all classes C, and for all methods M attached to C, all objects to which M sends a message must be instances of classes associated with the following classes:
>
> 1. The argument classes of M (including C).
> 2. The instance variable classes of C.
>    (Objects created by M, or by functions or methods which M calls, and objects in global variables are considers as arguments of M.)
>
> K. Lieberherr, I. Holland, and A. Riel. 1988. Object-oriented programming: an objective sense of style. In Conference proceedings on Object-oriented programming systems, languages and applications (OOPSLA '88). Association for Computing Machinery, New York, NY, USA, 323–334. DOI:https://doi.org/10.1145/62083.62113

### Classes, not Instances

To apply the law, look at the *classes** that are known to the consuming *class* `C`. If `C` stores an instance of class `A`, or can access an instance of `A` through global/hierarchical scope, or accepts an instance of `A` in a given method, then the damage is done. **That method of `C` already "knows about" `A`, and depends on the contract it provides**. That consumer method may call any method of any instance of `A`, no matter where it came from (or how complex it was to find it).

This is what differentiates the dog example from, say, fluent APIs. in a fluent API, you may chain a dozen function calls together, but each return value tends to be an instance of the same class! Each successive result may be a *new* instance, but the point is that **there is only one class**. You're counting classes, not instances or consecutive invocations.

*Presumably, this applies to all manner of types including specific interfaces; you don't "know about" `MySqlDbConnection` just because you know about `DbConnection`.

### The Spirit of the Law

Does the dog example break the Law of Demeter? We technically don't know, but it probably does. We don't have much information about the consuming context; does it "know about" dog legs because of some instance field we can't see? If so, the law permits the consumer to call *any* method of *any* leg.

Thus, the problem with the dog example isn't that the consumer accesses a deeply nested function (a direction for one particular among a set of legs on a dog), but that the consumer has to understand the concepts of a dog *and* of a set of legs *and* of individual legs. You don't fix it by hiding method calls, you fix it by decoupling from the classes that contain those methods.

**The Law of Demeter doesn't reduce coupling so much as it it keeps coupling explicit.** From there, you can more easily detect and address issues related to coupling.

### What about Wallets?

A popular analogy ([apparently created by David Bock](https://www2.ccs.neu.edu/research/demeter/demeter-method/LawOfDemeter/paper-boy/demeter.pdf)) when talking about the Law of Demeter is that of a paper boy that is owed money by a customer. The paper boy doesn't ask for a wallet so that he can grab the money, he just asks for the money. Who cares if the customer keeps it in a wallet, and why should the paper boy have to get the money from it anyway?

Interestingly, if the paper boy has a wallet of his own, this *does not break the Law of Demeter*! The paper boy knows how to use *a* wallet, so he knows how to use *the customer's* wallet. The real lesson of this scenario is to assign responsibilities properly and to keep implementation details (such as wallet vs. money clip vs. wad of bills) private.

### Tl;dr

Here are some possibilities for the name example, vis-à-vis the Law of Demeter, assuming `account.user()` returns type `User`.

1. Maybe there is nothing wrong with `account.user().fullName()`! If the consumer does other work involving `User`s, then the consumer has already "paid the price" of depending on the `User` class contract.
2. If it's not explicit now, then make it explicit! Work with the user directly - don't go through account. Instead of calling `account.user()`, have the consuming method explicitly depend on one `User` instance as a parameter. Now, even if `account.user()` suddenly returns a different class, that's somebody else's problem. The consumer can focus on working with a `User`. Notably, this only "adds" coupling to `User` for the consuming method in question, not the whole consuming class.
3. You could create a dedicated interface for situations like this. The consumer doesn't rely on a the `User`, but only on some abstraction that carries a smaller contract than a full `User`.